# hi im trying to update table from one database table to an other. but says i have an error

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE a SET a.id = b.id, a.searchkey = b.searchkey, a.taxid = b.taxid, a.name = b.name, 
         a.taxcategory = b.taxcategory, a.card = b.card, a.maxdebt = b.maxdebt, 
         a.address = b.address, a.address2 = b.address2, a.postal = b.postal, a.city = b.city, a.region = b.region, 
         a.country = b.country, a.firstname = b.firstname, a.lastname = b.lastname, 
         a.email = b.email, a.phone = b.phone, a.phone2 = b.phone2, a.fax = b.fax, a.notes = b.notes,
         a.visible = b.visible, a.curdate = b.curdate, a.curdebt = b.curdebt, a.image = b.image,
         a.isvip = b.isvip, a.discount = b.discount, a.memodate = b.memodate
FROM Purchase.customers
INNER JOIN customers b ON a.id = customers.id;
```

-

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatecentre.customersTrigger
ON customers
AFTER INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO purchase.customers
SELECT * 
FROM inserted
```

Comment: error points to here INNER JOIN customers b ON a.id = customers.id' at line 8

Comment: but does not show on the code on where the error is

Comment: [UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) - no FROM clause. [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) - no `INSERTED` pseudotable.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Purchase.customers a
INNER JOIN updatecentre.customers b ON a.id = b.id
SET {long assignments list}
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatecentre.customersTrigger
ON updatecentre.customers
AFTER INSERT
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO purchase.customers ( { table fields list } )
VALUES ( { NEW pseudotable fields list, like NEW.fieldname } )
```